# Insert nested supercolumn

Tags: cassandra, hector

How can I insert nested supercolumn (means supercolumn in a supercolumn) in Cassandra using Hector API. Below is the code for simple super column and it is working fine. But i want to add one super column in this too.

```
Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspaceOperator, stringSerializer);
List<HColumn<String,String>> colsList = new ArrayList<HColumn<String,String>>();
colsList.add(HFactory.createStringColumn("name", "tarun"));
colsList.add(HFactory.createStringColumn("age", "25"));
mutator.insert("deviceId", CF_SUPER, HFactory.createSuperColumn("10000", 
               colsList,stringSerializer, stringSerializer, stringSerializer));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't put a SuperColumn inside another SuperColumn in Cassandra.  This is not a limitation of Hector, this is just how Cassandra is implemented.

When I first started with Cassandra I read text descriptions of the data model for hours and my eyes glazed over and I didn't get it.  Then I saw a picture representation and grokked it instantly.  Check it out: http://www.javageneration.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Cassandra_DataModel_CheatSheet.pdf

Comment: Please have a look into the following link to know more about cassandra data mode.  http://arin.me/blog/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model

Comment: From your own link:  "A SuperColumn is a tuple w/ a binary name & a value which is a map containing an unbounded number of Columns – keyed by the Column‘s name."

To answer your original question -- you simply cannot put a Supercolumn inside another Supercolumn.  Cassandra just doesn't do it, so of course Hector doesn't do it either.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a super column inside another super column. You need to use a SuperColumnFamily that holds a collection of super columns. See [this](http://arin.me/blog/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model) great article by one of the guys who set up Cassandra at Digg for a good explanation of the data model.

Comment: I have already read this article and know that we can put super column inside another. But I want to do this through Hector Java API for Cassandra.

Comment: Do you know, how to add super column family using hector.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Hector library--I use Pelops and think it's a bit easier to grok--however, it's generally good practice to define your data model ahead of time and create the Column Families and Super column families prior to starting up the system. I personally prefer a script and the command line for doing that instead of trying to go through an API. It separates the access concern from the data model concern and lends itself to easier maintainability.

Comment: Can you provide a link, where I can get some examples of Pelops API. I have downloaded Pelops from the following location:-  https://github.com/s7/scale7-pelops

Comment: I used this: http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/pelops-the-beautiful-cassandra-database-client-for-java/ to get started and once I got past that, I started mucking around in the source code to figure things out.

Comment: I am able to insert 21000 records using pelops mutator. But when i exceed the no of records in a single batch, it shows me an error of connection abort.